# Vue RouterLink not working inside a component

Tags: vue.js, vue-router4

I have a very simple vue 3 project. In created a `Layout` *component* that has the navigation links which looks like this

```
<script setup>
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";

</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <div class="hidden md:flex md:w-64 md:flex-col md:fixed md:inset-y-0">
      <div
        class="flex-1 flex flex-col min-h-0 border-r border-gray-200 bg-white"
      >
        <div class="flex-1 flex flex-col pt-5 pb-4 overflow-y-auto">
          <div class="flex items-center flex-shrink-0 px-4">
            <h1 class="text-3xl font-extrabold text-gray-900">MiniSend</h1>
          </div>
          <nav class="mt-5 flex-1 px-4 bg-white space-y-2">
            <ul>
              <li class="mb-4">
                <RouterLink to="/dashboard" class="text-gray-700">
                  Dashboard</RouterLink
                >
              </li>

              <li class="mb-4">
                <RouterLink to="/settings" class="text-gray-700">
                  Settings</RouterLink
                >
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="md:pl-64 flex flex-col flex-1">
      <main class="flex-1">
        <div class="py-6">
          <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 md:px-8">
            <h1 class="text-2xl font-semibold text-gray-900">
              <slot name="pageTitle"></slot>
            </h1>
          </div>

          <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 md:px-8">
            <div class="py-4">
              <slot></slot>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

In my `Dashboard` *view* I imported the `Layout` *component* as seen below

```
<script setup>
import Layout from "../components/Layout.vue";

</script>

<template>
  <Layout>
    // ...content
  </Layout>
</template>
```

[image: Folder structure]

When the `Dashboard` *view* is served, I can see the links but I cannot click the links. I copied the same link code into the `Dashboard` view file and I was able to click and get routed to the right page.

Why are the links not working inside the component but work inside the view?

Comment: In composition api you must import the `RouterLink` component from `vue-router` before you can use it in the template. Are you getting an error in the console along the lines of:

"Unknown custom element: <RouterLink> - did you register the component correctly?"

Comment: There are no errors strangely. I also imported `RouterLink` from `vue-router` in the `Layout` component and that did not fix the issue. On the `Dashboard` view, I did not have to import `RouterLink` and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Consider providing a *runnable* [mcve]. Note you can easily import any repo into codesandbox.io.